Definition of a (holomorphic) differential form in the context of translation surfaces
I am a beginning graduate student with an interest in geometry, in particular, in translation surfaces. I am trying to learn from the recent text by Athreya & Masur.
My biggest point of confusion comes from pg. 21 where the text asserts:

A holomorphic 1-form or Abelian differential $\omega$ assigns to each local coordinate $z_\alpha$, a holomorphic function $\phi_{z_\alpha}(z_\alpha)$ such that in the overlapping charts $$\phi_{z_\beta}(z_\beta) \frac{dz_\beta}{dz_\alpha} = \phi_{z_\alpha}(z_\alpha)$$

I am having a hard time with a few parts of this. First of all, the expression $dz_\beta / dz_\alpha$ is not known to me, even in the context of smooth forms on a real manifold. It is not clear to me, given a differential form $\omega$, what the actual function $\phi$ ought to be.
My confusion is made worse by pg. 23, where the connection between the different definitions of translation surfaces are shown to be equivalent. The authors write

For any point $p \notin \Sigma$, let $U_\alpha$ be a simply connected domain containing $p$ such that $U_\alpha \cap \Sigma = \emptyset$. Let $w_\alpha : U_\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic chart. We assume $w_\alpha(p) = 0$. The corresponding holomorphic function $\phi_{w_\alpha}$ is nonzero at $w_\alpha(p)$...

The author goes on to describe an integration. However, I do not see how $\phi_{w_{\alpha}}$ can be seen to be nonzero at $w_\alpha(p)$. This ties in to my earlier question where I am failing to understand what these functions $\phi$ actually are.
In summary, I would like some help understanding what the derivative means in this context as it is not something I have yet seen in the theory of smooth manifolds, as well as some help understanding these $\phi$ functions.

It’s just the complex derivative of the chart transition map (which is essentially a map between open subsets of $\Bbb{C}$, so it’s something very basic). And regarding the function $\phi$, they’re just saying the unique function such that on this chart domain, $\omega =\phi(z), dz$.

There are better definitions than this, for instance, you can define these as holomorphic sections of the cotangent bundle. But it requires more mathematical sophistication on your part. Check, for instance, Griffiths and Harris, "Foundations of algebraic geometry."

What is your background? Have you seen the tangent bundle and cotangent bundle and differential forms? This is the same stuff. $dz_\beta/dz_\alpha$ is the analogue of the Jacobian matrix of the map between coordinate charts. We're just writing a holomorphic $1$-form locally as $\omega=\phi(z),dz$, where $z$ is a local holomorphic coordinate on the surface. The assumption that $\phi_{w_\alpha}$ is nonzero at $w_\alpha(p)$ is tantamount to assuming that $\omega(p)\ne 0$.

I have seen the tangent/cotangent bundles and differential forms in the real case. The faculty member at my institution used different notation than this textbook. I hadn't actually seen any complex geometry before.
Can you explain what you mean about this derivative notation being analogous to the Jacobian matrix in the real manifold setting?
